# How to get the absolute position (x, y coordinates) of a finger on a touchpad?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, touchpad, header-file

### Main question: How to get the absolute finger position on the touchpad?

I would like to get the absolute position (x, y coordinates) of a finger on a touchpad? I believe it is possible to extract it from the `synaptics`-family source code.

---

#### Subquestion: How to get the synaptics.h header?

I am trying to get synaptics.h so that I have access to the `SynapticsHwState` struct which allows to get the coordinates of a finger touching a touchpad.

---

This is what I've done so far:

1. I found out that I need to download linux headers, so I ran:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
   ```
2. The I found the header in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-686-pae/include/config/mouse/ps2/synaptics.h` it was **EMPTY** however.
3. It turns out that headers in the `include/config` path are [*usually* empty files due to some kernel building optimisations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537194/why-are-the-installed-linux-header-files-empty).
4. I'm stuck. I don't know how to get this header.

---

Here is [a link](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg36452.html) which might be helpful to answer my question. I don't understand much from what is written there however. I've tried to run `make headers_install` from `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-686-pae` but I got an error.

My distribution is BunsenLabs i386 Linux (a successor of CrunchBang, Debian based) with a `3.16.0-4-686-pae` kernel.

Comment: Looks like it might be in a package named libsynaptics

Comment: `apt-file` doesn't see anything but the `linux-headers` packages. You're going to have to look inside the source packages, which `apt-file` does not index. I'd look at the kernel sources.

Comment: @FaheemMitha There is a package called `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev`. I've got it installed, but I still have no `synaptics.h` on my system.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski I already said (see above) that `apt-file` does not find anything, other than the empty files you already referred to. Which means you aren't going to find anything in a binary package. You will have to look in the sources, probably the kernel sources.

Comment: @FaheemMitha. I just cannot find any information on where I should search...

Comment: Try searching in https://codesearch.debian.net/ for `synaptics.h`, or whatever else takes your fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to get the `synaptics.h` header however I found the way to get the position (x y coordinates) of a finger on a touchpad.

The software is called `evtest` and [the source code can be found here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/evtest) for example. There is a single `evtest.c` file and it is quite easy to modify it and extract the absolute finger position.

After all, I needed the `synaptics.h` only to get the coordinates. Hence I'll mark this question as solved.

Comment: Hello fellow programmer! Did you do it in C? I want to utilize these sources from Python but never imported non-adapted C modules in Python before...

Comment: @scythargon You may try to dig up interesting bits from here: https://github.com/0mp/io-touchpad

Answer (score 1):

Here that file is just a bunch of `#define`s for constants, they presumably haven't changed in some time. And it is found at `drivers/input/mouse/synaptics.h` in the vanilla kernel sources.

What exactly do you want to do with this file? It is *kernel internal* stuff.

Comment: I want to be able to get the coordinates of a finger when it touches touchpad. And there is a file called `synproto.h` in the sources of synatpics (ftp://ftp.fau.de/netbsd/NetBSD-release-6/xsrc/external/mit/xf86-input-synaptics/dist/src/synproto.h) which has `SynapticsHwState` struct. This struct holds x, y and z coordinates.